# Displaying the contents of a variable in the select field when editing in react bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

In the form of editing, I have `input select`. In the framework `ant design` the contents of the`status` variable are displayed in the input field. It works.
In the `react-bootstrap` framework, attempts to display the contents of`status` variable are not working. how to set this value in the input field?

**Framework Ant design**

```
 const status = 'P'; 

  <Select 
    style={{ width: 170 }}
    value={status}
    onChange={(e) => this.props.handleChangeStatus(e)}>
      <Option value="0">N</Option>
      <Option value="10">P</Option>
      <Option value="20">O</Option>
  </Select>
```

**Framework react-bootstrap**

```
  <Form.Control 
    as="select" 
    value ={status}
    onChange={(e) => this.props.handleChangeStatus(e)}
  >
    <option value="0">N</option>
    <option value="10">P</option>
    <option value="20">O</option>
  </Form.Control>
```

Comment: Try to set `status` to one of the `<option>` elements' values instead of their text content.

Comment: @Titus When  I set   <option>{status}</option><option value="0">N</option>
    <option value="10">P</option>
    <option value="20">O</option> I have example NNPO. I have the same two option

Answer (score 0):

you can use react-bootstrap dropdown like this:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Form, DropdownButton, Dropdown } from "react-bootstrap";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [value, setvalue] = React.useState("");
  const handleDropdown = e => {
    setvalue(e.target.name);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Form>
        <DropdownButton
          className="my-2"
          title={value === "" ? "select speaker" : value}
        >
          <Dropdown.Item name="Value 1" onClick={e => handleDropdown(e)}>
            Value 1
          </Dropdown.Item>
          <Dropdown.Item name="Value 2" onClick={e => handleDropdown(e)}>
            Value 2
          </Dropdown.Item>
        </DropdownButton>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

also check this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bitter-bird-xc93f) for better understanding.